# Selecting the last value from the dropdown and disable it for other dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 drop-downs with values: `Select`, `One`, `Two`, `Three` and following is the HTML.

```
<select class="dpdown" id="box1">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Tow</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select> 
<select class="dpdown" id="box2">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Tow</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select> 
<select class="dpdown" id="box3">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Tow</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Conditions

1. First of all the jQuery function should store the current values from all the boxes.
2. If the user select `One` from `#box1`, then it (`One`) should be disabled from all other boxes, and if `Two` is selected from `#box1` again, then `Two` is disabled from other boxes and `One` gets enabled. i.e. the last value is disabled not all the values.
3. Also to be noted that the user can select from any of the dropdowns whether it is box1/box2 or box3.

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box1').data('pre', $(this).val()); // added this line to get the pre value.
    $("select").change(function(e){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var before_change = $(this).data('pre');
        alert(before_change); // alert shows blank values
    });
});
```

I want to do this with jQuery. Please help.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have written yourself in an attempt to solve this issue.

Comment: editing the question for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```js
$(".dpdown").on("change", function() {
    var sel = $(this).val();
    $(".dpdown").find("option").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".dpdown").not(this).find("option[value='" + sel + "']").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dpdown" id="box1">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Tow</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select> 
<select class="dpdown" id="box2">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Tow</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select> 
<select class="dpdown" id="box3">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Tow</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
var $selects = $('.dpdown').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $selects
        .children().prop('disabled', false)
        .end().not(this)
        .find('[value="' + val + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dpdown" id="box1">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select> 
<select class="dpdown" id="box2">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select> 
<select class="dpdown" id="box3">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select>
```

The idea is that you bind change event to all select boxes. Then when event happens you enable all options from all selectboxes, then you find option with matching value from other selects (other then current `this`) and disable them.

Comment: Adding one more point to conditions : if i select "One" from box1 and "Two" from box2 then in box3 both should be disabled. Can it also be possible with the above code.. But good solution from your side.

Answer (score 0):

You code simple :

```
<script>
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $("select option").removeAttr('disabled');
  $("select option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled','disabled')
});
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kanaso/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**UPDATED**

```
var $selects = $(".dpdown").change(function() {
    var selectedValues = [];

    $.each($selects, function(index, select) {
        var value = $(select).val();
        if (value != "Select") {
            selectedValues.push(value);
        }  
    });

    $selects
       .find("option")
       .prop("disabled", false);

    $.each(selectedValues, function(index, value) {

        $selects
            .find("option[value='" + value +"']")
            .not(":selected")
            .prop("disabled", true);

    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xzjfpfbo/3/)

Comment: It has one issue, the selected value must be enabled only for the box from where the value is selected. i.e. if one is selected from box1 then it should be enabled for box1 and disabled for other. 
Also check the condition: the last value is to be disbaled not all. this query is disables all the values even selecting from box1. check condition "2" in question mentioned above.